# there is no form-horizontal item in intellisense list

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

i'm using vs 2016 ...
i downloaded bootstrap 4.1.3 and added two folder name css and js to my project.
i added a html page to my project and link bootstrap.css to the header of this page.
the problem is that when i want to add a form tag (with form-horizontal class) to body of HTML page, there is no form-horizontal item in the list of Intellisense items. the most of the bootstrap items are exist in the list , but neither form-horizontal and "form-in line" isn't in the list.
also my form isn't shown horizontally, it is shown vertically.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <form class="form-horizontal">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email_id" class="control-label col-md-2">Email</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <!-- This is a new div -->
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email_id" name="email_name" placeholder="name@domain.com">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                <!--New div, offset because there is no label -->
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just loaded bootstrap with cdn link and it works also you have to add jquery and bootstrap js at the end of you html page. From your code snippet jquery and bootstrap was not included. You need to include them as well. You can check it from the code snippet written below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <form class="form-horizontal">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email_id" class="control-label col-md-2">Email</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <!-- This is a new div -->
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email_id" name="email_name" placeholder="name@domain.com">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                <!--New div, offset because there is no label -->
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form> 
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks Faizan , i copied your code and pasted it into my HTML code completely , but still displayed vertically.

Comment: Is the bootstrap loading on your page or any error in the console

Comment: The bootstrap is loaded ,the style of labels is changed to the bootstrap style , but just it doesn't changed to horizontal style.

Comment: after several day ,finally i find out that there is no form-horizontal style in bootstrap 4 . in bs4 , there is two style for forms : 1-stacked form 2-inline form ....

Comment: But in the above snippet i have used bootstrap 4 and it uses form-horizontal .